# Prolog find permutations of a list, values inside the permutation cannot be the same value

Tags: prolog, clpfd

```
length(List, 5),
fd_domain(List, 1, 5),
fd_all_different(List).
```

Here I created a list of 5 elements and I want to make sure that these 5 elements are of different values. I want to find another way to replace the fd_all_different to another predicates, is there anyway I can do it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The answer is "yes". But perhaps you should read [ask]?

Comment: You tagged this SWI Prolog, but the predicates you're using (`fd_...`) are from GNU Prolog.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? You mean you don't want to use `fd_all_different`? If not, why not? Perhaps you can show at least one example of the kind of query you want to perform and expected results.

Comment: To formulate your example in SWI-Prolog, you'll need to load the CLP(FD) library: `:- use_module(library(clpfd)).`. The corresponding goal to your fd_domain/2 would be `List ins 1..5` and the corresponding predicate to fd_all_different/1 is `all_distinct(List)`. To get actual numbers instead of residual goals, you'll also have to append a goal `label(List)`. All of the above will give you all 5!=120 permutations of that five element list. I would also point you to SWI-Prolog's [CLP(FD) documentation page](http://www.swi-prolog.org/man/clpfd.html).